# Jquery: Alter a specific sibling class that belongs to an immediate parent.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

On my HTML page, I have several forms.

They all follow a pattern:

1. Each Form is in a div called `"form-optional"`
2. Inside this DIV is a checkbox, which is wrapped in the class `"form-enable"`
3. The actual form has a class of `"form-main"`.

I want use Jquery, so that when the user clicks on the checkbox, the "form-main" becomes hidden. However, only the form that belongs to the same "form-optional" div as the checkbox that is clicked should be hidden. All other forms should be left unchanged.

I know you can use the Jquery commands [.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) to locate the parent of a class and then combine it with [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to find a specific class within that parent(). However, when I use these commands, it doesn't seem to work.

**[JSFIDDLE is here](http://jsfiddle.net/8xrQe/)**

Here is my Jquery:

```
// JavaScript Document
(function($)
{


$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".form-optional .form-enable input").click(function(){


        if(($this).attr('checked')){

            $(this).parent().find('.form-main').fadeIn();
        }

        else
        {
            $(this).parent().find('.form-main').fadeOut();
        }
    });
    });


})(jQuery);
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-optional">
    <p class="form-enable">
        <input name="personaldetails" type="checkbox" value="">No Personal Details
    </p>
    <p class="form-explanation">If this product is a gift, you can tick the box, to omit the personal details</p>


    <form name="frmPersonal" class="form-main">

        Name:
        <input type="text" name="ordPersonalInfo1" value="" onkeyup="Restrict_Chars(this.form.ordPersonalInfo1,30);">

    </form>

</div>



<div class="form-optional">
    <p class="form-enable">
        <input name="friendsdetails" type="checkbox" value="">No Friends Details
    </p>
    <p class="form-explanation">If you have no friends, you can tick the box to omit friends</p>


    <form name="frmPersonal" class="form-main">

        Name:
        <input type="text" name="ordPersonalInfo1" value="" onkeyup="Restrict_Chars(this.form.ordPersonalInfo1,30);">

    </form>

</div>
```

Comment: in your if statement, the $ should be outside the parenthesis to reference the input

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent of the checkbox is the `p` element, which is why you are not finding the form element (and you need to fix your $ placement on the checked attribute. You can use parents() but then you have to specify that you only want the first element otherwise it would be applied to all elements with the class. Try:

```
   $(".form-optional .form-enable input").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')){
      $(this).closest('div').find('.form-main').fadeOut();
    }
    else
    {
       $(this).closest('div').find('.form-main').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Also, I switched the order in my example since you want to hide when the checkbox is clicked, not unclicked:

http://jsfiddle.net/8xrQe/5/

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this:

```
$(".form-optional .form-enable input").click(function () {
    if (($this).attr('checked')) {
        $(this).parents().find('.form-main').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $(this).parents().find('.form-main').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Since `.parent()` method only searches one level up the DOM tree, but `.parents()` searches upto the top level of the DOM tree.

Hence, when you use `.parent()` method, it is not able to find the `form-optional` class div and thus your code is not working.

Answer (score 1):

It is because `form-main` is not a descendant of the parent element, it is a sibling of the checkbox elements parent. So one possible solution based on your markup is to find the  `form-optional` element and then find the `form-main` within it.

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $(".form-optional .form-enable input").change(function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            $(this).closest('.form-optional').find('.form-main').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.form-optional').find('.form-main').fadeOut();
        }
    }).change();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/TthF5/)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.parents()`, but specifying a selector for it.

Try this:

```
var enableInput = function()
{
    var checkbox = $("input[type='checkbox']");

    checkbox.click(function(){
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).parents(".form-optional").find(".form-main").fadeIn();
        } else {
            $(this).parents(".form-optional").find(".form-main").fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
enableInput();
```

[Example in JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8xrQe/2/).

Answer (score 0):

Use [**.next()**](http://api.jquery.com/next/):

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the
>   **`.next()` method allows us to search through the immediately following
>   sibling** of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery
>   object from the matching elements.